# Valgrind interface for emacs

Tags: debugging, c++, c, gdb

Is there an interface similar to 'gdb-mi' for using Valgrind in emacs?

What are some ways to use Valgrind inside emacs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799760/is-there-a-emacs-valgrind-interface

Comment: This question seems to be asking how to use Valgrind inside emacs, not emacs inside Valgrind